# Firebase analytics for different build types

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I want to integrate firebase analytics to both of my android and iOS app.

For android, I have a single flavour with 3 different build types. Dev staging and release. All these build types have the same application ID.

For historical reasons, I cannot change the build type to include a different suffix to differentiate.

On firebase analytics, I would like to have two dashboard! The first to include data from dev and staging. The second to include data from release.

The question is - how should I create the projects and link the google-service.json? Is that possible to do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside `src` directory create different directories for each build type. Then place `google-services.json` for specific types inside the respective directories.

For example I have two build types `debug` and `release`, so this is how it works

[image]

So you will have three directories - dev, staging and release and they will have their own `google-services.json` file.

Comment: I may sound crazy, but what you have looks like 3 different "product flavors" - not build types.

Comment: Oh wow. Reading the gradle console seems to indicate you are absolutely correct! I didn't know the gradle plugin already covered this case.